# PHP global variable shared between two files

Tags: php

I have two different files in the same folder, the first one is called "form.php" the second one is called "add.php", I can't get the value of the global variable in "form.php"

"form.php"

```
<?php
include("add.php");
global $Resultat;
echo $Resultat;
?>
```

"add.php"

```
<?php
global $Resultat;
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["val_1"]) || empty($_POST["val_2"])) {
        header("Location: form.php?FillTheForm");
        exit();
    } else {
        $Resultat=$_POST["val_1"]+$_POST["val_2"];
        echo "$Resultat"; //this works if I don't use header (the next instruction).
        header("Location: form.php"); // I want to redirect and still echo the value in "form.php".
    }
}
```

If I don't use the header in the else statement it echos the value in "add.php" but i want to redirect to "form.php" and echo it there.

Comment: Depending on the data, you could use PHP cookie or session.

Comment: Yes, though i want to use global variables, am wondering why whenever I redirect to the "form.php" my value is lost and I can't echo it.

Comment: "global" is just a variable scope. It does not persist across distinct invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to redirect to "form.php" and echo it there.

echo ' window.location = "add.php" ';

Do this instead of INCLUDE.

Comment: I did that in "form.php" and it echos that as a string, it did not work.

Comment: Hi OussamaMater,
Sorry for not giving you the proper form of  window.location.
It is JavaScript.
Look at this:
JavaScript Window Location
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp